# how to display a REG file entries in a memo Box in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to display an exported .reg file , eg. abc.eg; i want to display its contents in a memo box. i am using Delphi 7. This is the code i have used:

```
         edit2.Text :=openDialog2.FileName;
         ShowMessage(edit2.Text) ;
        fileData2.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text);
         for i:=0 to fileData2.Count-1 do
         begin
              str:=fileData2[i];
              memo2.Lines.Append(str);
         end;
```

This code displays the content of INI file correctly.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Cosmin is right about the Unicode issue. As an aside your code above would most easily be written as: `memo2.Lines.LoadFromFile(edit2.Text)` but that's just a comment on the code - you still need to deal with UTF-16 -> ANSI.

Comment: Please mention your delphi version explicitly.

Comment: @warren question states delphi 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.REG` files produced by the `regedit.exe` are plain text files encoded using UTF-16. Delphi 7 is not Unicode-enabled and it cant directly handle it: You'll need to do the conversion to AnsiString yourself.

Here's a routine that will load a text file into a `TStrings`; It supports loading UTF-8, UTF-16 Little Endian and considers everything else to be Ansi. Uses the BOM to check the file type, and I tested the routine on Delphi 7 with all 3 types of files (UTF-8, UTF-16 and Ansi):

```
procedure LoadTextFile(const FileName:string; const Strings: TStrings);
var FS: TFileStream;
    Buff: PByteArray;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    if FS.Size = 0 then Exit;
    Buff := AllocMem(FS.Size + 2); // Enough space to read the whole file and space to add a terminator
    try
      // Read the file
      FS.ReadBuffer(Buff^, FS.Size);
      // Init the NULL terminator
      Buff[FS.Size] := 0;
      Buff[FS.Size+1] := 0;
      // Check the BOM
      if (Buff[0] = $ff) and (Buff[1] = $fe) then
        begin
          // UTF-16, Little Endian encoding
          Strings.Text := PWideChar(@Buff[2]); // Skip BOM, automatic UTF16->ANSI encoding
        end
      else if (Buff[0] = $ef) and (Buff[1] = $bb) and (BUff[2] = $bf) then
        begin
          // UTF8 Encoding
          Strings.Text := Utf8ToAnsi(UTF8String(PAnsiChar(@Buff[3]))); // Skip BOM, explicit UTF8->ANSI
        end
      else
        begin
          // Unknown or unsupported BOM, assume Plain Ansi File
          Strings.Text := PAnsiChar(Buff);
        end
    finally FreeMemory(Buff);
    end;
  finally FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In the particular case of loading the `.reg` file, you can do something like this:

```
LoadTextFile('C:\test.reg', Memo1.Lines);
```

or

```
LoadTextFile(Edit1.Text, Memo1.Lines);
```

Comment: @sunandan, see the edit. I assume you were looking at an older version of the page, since I added the code sample pretty fast after the initially answering.

Comment: You probably want some error checking in case the file is empty. And it may not be zero-terminated. And why not just use `inc(PW)` to skip the BOM?

Comment: Actually, This code will simply fail because files are not null-terminated.

Comment: @David, good catch about the null-terminator. When I tested it didn't AV and I didn't scroll the memo to see the junk!

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to Cosmin's answer, I offer this version of Utf16 -> Ansi converstion:

```
function ReadUtf16TextFile(const FileName: string): string;
const
  WideCharSize = SizeOf(WideChar);
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Utf16: WideString;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  Try
    if Stream.Size>WideCharSize then begin
      SetLength(Utf16, (Stream.Size div WideCharSize)-1);
      Stream.Position := WideCharSize;//skip the BOM
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Utf16[1], Length(Utf16)*WideCharSize);
      Result := Utf16;
    end else begin
      Result := '';
    end;
  Finally
    Stream.Free;
  End;
end;
```

It is robust in the face of empty files, files that aren't null-terminated which is in fact the norm. (Cosmin has probably fixed his version by now.)

You can use it like this:

```
memo2.Lines.Text := ReadUtf16TextFile(edit2.Text);
```

If you wanted to get cute you could look for the BOM in the file and then decide to load UTF-16, UTF-8 and so on depending on what the BOM was.  In this code I have made the assumption that the file is encoded as UTF-16 with a BOM, as is your file.

Comment: @David, you're not checking the BOM! What if the file is acutally UTF-8 encoded, or, god forbid, Ansi? (yes, I am promoting my own improved version, because mine is handling all 3)

Comment: @Cosmin You've missed off UTF16-BE and the two UTF-32 encodings.   ;-)  This is turning into an arms race! I'd be happy to delete my offering if you made yours a little more functional. I'm joking about the other encodings. You function would be better off returning a string than pushing into a Strings. I also think my use of WideString is cleaner than your PWideChar stuff in particular the handling of null terminator.

Comment: @David, my code deals with the BOM, and because of that needs to load the file before deciding what size the BOM is and where the actual payload starts. Since I've got the data in memory, using `PWideChar` seemed to be the natural option.

Comment: @Cosmin Nah, you just read the first 3 bytes of the file and then work it out from there. Using pointers is why your code is somewhat messy, no offence intended.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very bad (and slow!) way of loading a text file into a `TMemo` control!

It will add one line at a time, and repaint the control each time!

If you simply want to load a text file into a `TMemo` control, just do

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
```

as in

```
  with TOpenDialog.Create(nil) do
    try
      if Execute then
        Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

If you really want to add the contents of the text file below the current content of the control, you can use the `AddStrings` method, as in

```
var
  newlines: TStringList;
begin
  with TOpenDialog.Create(nil) do
    try
      if Execute then
      begin
        newlines := TStringList.Create;
        try
          newlines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
          Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(newlines);
        finally
          newlines.Free;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

And, if you for some reason really *need* to add one line at a time, as you did in your original code, then for God's sake please surround the block with `Lines.BeginUpdate` and `Lines.EndUpdate`, so that the control isn't repainted for every added line!

Comment: @David: I know. But it needs to be said.